# Программа закрывается до того, как напечатать ответ

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Почему, когда я пишу такой код:

```
pervoe=input("Input first number")
vtoroe=input("Input second number")
print(pervoe+vtoroe)
```

программа читает 1 и 2 строку, а потом закрывается, не читая 3 строку. 
Почему?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что 3 строка не читается? Как и где вы запускаете программу?

Может быть, все выводится, просто поскольку дальше нет никаких инструкций, то программа и завершается? Вставьте 4 строкой еще один input, по-любому увидите вывод на экран.

Comment: Спасибо большое у меня все заработало! Только вот не очень удобно и додуматься не могу, что написать в 4 строке. Может, Вы знаете какую-нибудь команду, чтобы моя программа задержалась? Например, в QBasic такая команда пишется вот так - sleep 1000. Значит, что программа задержится на 1 секунду, а после выключиться сама. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если знаете. А так большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Медведь https://www.google.ru/search?q=python+sleep

    import time
    time.sleep(0.5) // заснуть на полсекунды

Comment: А еще вы можете открыть командную строку (`cmd`) и запускать скрипт уже внутри. Тогда, вы всегда будете видеть ее вывод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В качестве ответа вы получаете строковые данные, их нужно преобразовать в целые или дробные числа.

В вашем случае:

```
pervoe=int(pervoe) #если подразумевается ввод целых чисел или    
vtoroe=float(vtoroe) #если подразумевается ввод дробных чисел
```

можно сразу получить числовой ответ пользователя вложенным способом:

```
pervoe=int(input("Input first number"))
```

Для того чтобы программа не закрывалась сразу, вставьте такую строку:

```
input("\n\nНажмите Enter чтобы выйти .")
```